# Collection class has a private constructor, why not make it abstract?

Tags: java, collections

```
public class Collections {
    // Suppresses default constructor, ensuring non-instantiability.
    private Collections() {
    }
...
```

All the included methods are static, if I were coding something similar I would have made the Collections.class abstract, but still have a private constructor - why is the class not defined as abstract ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A class being `abstract` implies that it can (and *is intended* to) be extended, which is not the case with the `Collections` class. That's my guess.

Comment: Actually, `abstract` means exactly that the class cannot be instantiated, nothing more or less. It does not by itself imply that subclassing is welcome. For example, there is no requirement on an abstract class to have any abstract, or even overridable methods.

Comment: `abstract` doesn't forbid subclasses, though.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik "It does not by itself imply that subclassing is welcome" -- you might be assuming the logician's definition of imply, while we're using the colloquial meaning. In the fuzzy brains of the majority of developers who see an `abstract` class, they *will* infer that this means they're expected to subclass it, or at least go looking for some concrete subclass to use.

Comment: @KevinBourrillion True, later I thought about it more and I withdraw my remark, which stems from 10 years ago when we actually taught students something to that effect. Memory is fading, but I think Thinking in Java by Bruce Eckel (popular at the time) suggested to use `abstract` to prevent instantiation.

Answer (score 5):

The `Collections` class isn't meant to be extended *or subclassed* -- it's meant to just be a provider of static utility methods.  If it were abstract, users could subclass it, and the JDK designers didn't want that.

Comment: its not final so it can be subclassed ... ?

Comment: Having only `private` constructors _also_ stops it from being subclassed, because any subclass wouldn't be able to access a superconstructor in its constructor.  It's sort of a way of making it final without using the `final` keyword.  (You can try to subclass it yourself, and you'll get an error message that it can't access the superclass constructor.)

Comment: I just did. Why not just specify final though ?

Comment: As to that -- I'm under the impression that the advantages of `final` just hadn't caught on with Josh Bloch and co. when they were building the Collections Framework initially.  Frankly, I think that in retrospect, most of the Collections classes should've been final -- up to and including `HashSet`, `ArrayList`, and all those implementation classes.

Answer (score 4):

You could make it

- an `abstract` class
- or an `enum` with no instances
- or a `final` class

IMHO, It depends on what was the flavour when the class was first written, as there is littel reason to change it later.

Comment: Hmmmm.  Can you actually have an enum with no instances?  I didn't think you could.

Comment: I have helper/utility classes like `enum Utility {; /* static methods */ }`

Comment: Huh.  Cool!  I did not know that.

Comment: Actually, the private constructor prevents instantiation **and** extension, and is thus the shortest syntax to use (pre-Java 5). Making it just abstract or just final (cannot use both) would **still** require the private constructor for the other property.

Comment: enum with no instances, yowzers

Answer (score 2):

In addition to its "technical" side (i.e. inability to instantiate), `abstract` has a semantic side facing the user of your library: it communicates an *intent* for others to extend the class. This is not something you are expected to do with `Collections`, hence marking it `abstract` would be a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common practice, used in utility classes that only have static methods. Making the class abstract wouldn't make sense, as there are no instance methods defined.  It's to prevent someone from creating an instance where it's unneeded.

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("b", "c", "a");
new Collections().sort(myList);
```

where

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("b", "c", "a");
Collections.sort(myList);
```

is the "correct" way of using the utility class.

Comment: In fact, there's nothing wrong with preventing instantiation by `abstract` -- just that you still need the private constructor to prevent subclassing.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I understand what you are saying.  But when I make class Abstract, I do it because the intent is that the class **should** be subclassed and instantiated, not as a means to ensure it can't be instantiated.  I'm not sure if I'm explaining it well.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I thought about it, maybe it really would be bad style to make an abstract class with private constructor. Ten years ago, though, we used to teach students that this was ok. I kind of remember Thinking in Java said something to that effect.